# How to tunnel Keycloak server from localhost to ngrok while frontend is tunneled?

Tags: angular, spring, keycloak, ngrok, tunneling

I'm facing an issue with setting up ngrok for my development environment. I have successfully set up ngrok to tunnel my frontend application running on localhost:4200, but I'm unsure how to tunnel my Keycloak server, which is running on localhost:8180, to ngrok.

Problem:

I'm using ngrok to expose my frontend application to the internet for testing purposes, and it works perfectly fine.
However, I'm also using Keycloak for authentication, and it's running locally on localhost:8180.
When I tunnel my frontend using ngrok, it's accessible via a public URL, but requests to Keycloak fail because it's still running on localhost.
Desired Solution:

I want to be able to access both my frontend application and Keycloak through ngrok so that I can test the entire authentication flow.
Ideally, I'd like to configure ngrok to tunnel both applications simultaneously.
What I've Tried:

I've attempted to run ngrok http 8180 to tunnel the Keycloak server directly, but it doesn't seem to work as expected.
I've looked into ngrok's documentation, but I couldn't find clear instructions on how to tunnel multiple applications simultaneously or how to properly configure it for my use case.
Request for Assistance:

Can someone provide guidance on how to tunnel the Keycloak server from localhost:8180 to ngrok so that it's accessible via a public URL?
Alternatively, is there a recommended approach for setting up ngrok to tunnel both the frontend application and the Keycloak server simultaneously?
Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!